# Jersey: How to make a POST request using a Client with Query Parameters and an image?

Tags: java, image, post, jersey

I'm using Jersey 2.22. My code:

```
   WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("https://api.someurl.com");
   MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();

   map.add("param1", "1");
   map.add("param2", "2");
   map.add("param3", "3");

   Response response = target.request().post(Entity.form(map));
```

This works well, however, I want to include an image and I have no idea how to do it. I've read the documentation and couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out that a `jersey-media-multipart` module existed. I added it to my dependencies and changed my code to:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
WebTarget target = client.target("https://apisomeurl.com");

MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
multiPart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

//Image here
FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("image", new File("/some/img/path/img.png"));
multiPart.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);

//MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE because I'm expecting a JSON response from the server           
String str = target.queryParam("param1", "1")
                   .queryParam("param2", "2")
                   .queryParam("param3", "3")
                   .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                   .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()), String.class);
```